# Problem with PHP number increment

Tags: php, increment

I have a simple form that has a name and a message fields. When user submitted a form, the page display a User ID number what user has entered and a file "data.db" is created upon submission when it hasn't exist in server. The user ID number would begin from1 and increment by 1 every time a new submission is stored.

The file have the following format:

```
1|{name1}|{gender1}|{email1}|{phone1}
2|{name2}|{gender2}|{email2}|{phone2} ...
```

However, I am having trouble with display the user number, it just stayed at 1 every time the form is submitted.

The variable I created $userid doesn't seems to be incrementing at all...

Here is php code used for displaying the data after form submission...

```
 <?php
     include("email.php");

     $userid += 1;

     echo "<b><u>Your submission has been added!</u></b> <br />";
     echo "User ID: " . $userid . "<br /><br />";
     echo "Name = ";
     echo $_POST["name"];
     echo "<br /> Gender = ";
     echo $_POST["gender"];
     echo "<br /> E-Mail = ";
     echo $_POST["email"];
     echo "<br /> Phone No. = ";
     echo $_POST["phone"];
     echo "<br />";
     echo "<p>Thank You</p>";

     $entry = $userid . "|" . $_POST["name"] . "|" . $_POST["gender"] . "|" . $_POST["email"] . "|" . $_POST["phone"] . "\n";

     file_put_contents("data.db", $entry, FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);

     echo "Confirm email sent!";
     ?>
```

Comment: Where are you initializing `$userid`?

Comment: your script dont know how often its called. so userid will always be one. you can use _SESSION if it is based on the same user in the same session, or you have to store the incrment value permanent (like in a db or file)

Answer (score 3):

The value of $userid is not kept on different loads of the page.  You could store it in the $_SESSION global to access it, but that would only work if (a) you are using sessions, and (b) it is the same user at the same terminal in the same session.

What I think you want is that value to be used (and incremented) when any user views the page.  You'd therefore need to store the value in, say, a file or an SQL database.  Look it up on page load, increment it, write it back to disk.  But then you have simultaneous access issues - what if two users open the page simultaneously - you may not get a unique [incremented] number.

I'd suggest using some kind of SQL back end, and having it auto-generate a unique ID to use in the output, thus guaranteeing you a unique userid each time.

Answer (score 1):

As i wrote in the comment, your script has no way to know how often it is called. So you have to store the userid permanent.

you can use this (WARNING: i dont take care of filelhandling, eg. when 2 forms are submited in the exact same time):

```
<?php
 include("email.php");
 include('counter.php');

 $userid += 1;

 file_put_contents('counter.php', '<?php $userid = '.$userid.';');

 echo "<b><u>Your submission has been added!</u></b> <br />";
 echo "User ID: " . $userid . "<br /><br />";
 echo "Name = ";
 echo $_POST["name"];
 echo "<br /> Gender = ";
 echo $_POST["gender"];
 echo "<br /> E-Mail = ";
 echo $_POST["email"];
 echo "<br /> Phone No. = ";
 echo $_POST["phone"];
 echo "<br />";
 echo "<p>Thank You</p>";

 $entry = $userid . "|" . $_POST["name"] . "|" . $_POST["gender"] . "|" . $_POST["email"] . "|" . $_POST["phone"] . "\n";

 file_put_contents("data.db", $entry, FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);

 echo "Confirm email sent!";
 ?>
```

Comment: Ah. Ok. Perhaps I can create a text file called "userid.txt" with '0' as the content. Have the script to read the value and then increment the value inside by 1 and resave the file?

Comment: why a textfile... use my code its writes a phpfile with the userid variable. and includes it automaticly. (you should create the counter.php with `<?php $userid = 0;` befor the first run of course.

Comment: make sure the counter.php is writeable.

Comment: @Rufinus - I'm not sure this would work with a heavily loaded system - you could potentially end up with two (or more!) users simultaneously causing attempts to write to counter.php.  Only one of these would succeed, meaning that the others would fail the call to file_put_contents - not to mention the fact that the multiple users could all have read from the same version of counter.php - which is definitely not what you want!

Comment: nothing i didnt mentioned.... but if you read the code the file is included and imideatlly writen, this is done in a few milliseconds the load would have to be extremly high, but then i would use a real database. but as long as he is using the same mechanism for storing the file, i guess the load cant not be that high :-)